# How do I check when a user clicks the correct button?

Tags: java, android-studio

So, I am pretty new to programming, and even newer to Android Studio and Java, and i've been struggling with this one...

So, in my activity i have 9 buttons, each with their own colour. When the user clicks the 'start' button, the name of one of the colours is randomly chosen and appears (Did this with an array). Then the user has to click the button with the correct colour.

The thing I'm having trouble with is checking whether and when the user has clicked the right button.
Any help with how to go about this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you try with onClickListner() on the Button, then pass a implementation of the Listner handling the color change. Android will automatically take care when user clicks on the Button on behalf of you.

Answer (score 0):

Check which button was clicked and then check if the clicked button has the right color:

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
int colorValue = buttonColor.getColor();
if(colorValue==rightColor){...}
```